# programmatically adding buttons and OnClientClick but still having post back issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, onclientclick

I am trying to hide some divs using Javascript but i think the post back keeps reloading the page.
To make things more complicated my buttons are added programmatically by my code behind.

```
foreach (string line in thefilters)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.ID = Convert.ToString(line);
            newButton.Text = Convert.ToString(line);
            newButton.CssClass = "tblbutton";
            //newButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "hide_div("+newButton.ID+")");
            newButton.OnClientClick = "return hide_div('" + newButton.ID + "')";
            pnl_left.Controls.Add(newButton);
        }
```

My javascript is located in the header as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function hide_div(filter) {
            var pnl_right = document.getElementById("pnl_right");
            var listofelements = pnl_right.getElementsById("div");
            for (var i = 0; i < listofelements.length; i++) {
                if (listofelements[i].id.indexOf(filter) == 0) {

                    document.getElementById(listofelements[i].id).style.display = 'inline';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById(listofelements[i].id).style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
```

I may have issues in the javascript for what i want to achieve but i am confident that if i can stop the postback then i can solve the javascript myself..

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console? There may be an error in Javascript, which prevents the `return false` from executing and therefore not actually doing want you want. Can you put an `alert` somewhere in your Javascript function to see if it's actually being called?

Comment: Your OnClientClick should probably be set to "return hide_div('" + newButton.ClientID + "')";

Answer (score 1):

You have not showed in which event you are adding controls. But I am assuming from your problem that you are doing this in Page_Load. If yes, try and move in **OnInit** event.

Second, in Page_Load you need to check

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//your code for adding controls
}
```

Hope that helps.